# Git diff shows too many files

Tags: git, tfs, git-merge, git-diff, git-log

When creating a TFS pull request into QA, I got a shock when it said there were 300 files modified, despite expecting no more than 20.

When I run `git log --oneline --graph QA..MyCode`, it returns 8 commits (the same ones as shown in TFS):

```
* 4db6392 Message Hidden (3 files)
* 9fdda73 Message Hidden (4 files)
*   64bbab8 Message Hidden (3 files)
|\
| * 1ca059d Merge master -> MyCode (13 files)
| * 3200fe0 Message Hidden (1 file)
| * e27653c Message Hidden (1 file)
| * cd57d2f Message Hidden (1 file)
* e2afeef Message Hidden (9 files)
```

The number of files in brackets was found using `git show --name-only *SHA*`, in many cases the same file was altered on different commits.

However when I run `git diff --name-only QA..MyCode`, it lists 304 files.

The commit before the last e2afeef is 41e68bb, if I run `git log QA..41e68bb` as expected it returns nothing.  But running `git diff --name-only QA..41e68bb` returns around 680 files.

I'm very confused!  Can anyone explain what's going on, or point me in the right direction of how I can investigate further?

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of `<commit>..<commit>` for `diff` is not the same as it's for `log` (`rebase` etc.). From `git diff --help`

> ```
>    Comparing branches
>
>            $ git diff topic master    (1)
>            $ git diff topic..master   (2)
>            $ git diff topic...master  (3)
>
>        1. Changes between the tips of the topic and the master branches.
>        2. Same as above.
>        3. Changes that occurred on the master branch since when the topic branch was started off it.
> ```

I think what you need is the example `(3)` -> `git diff --name-only QA...MyCode`
**Update**
Running `git merge-base --all QA MyCode` gave 2 sha1 - clear sign of criss-cross merge.

```
--o--p--q--r--s   <-QA
   \/
   /\
--A--B--C--D--E   <-MyCode
```

it's better to rewrite the history of `MyCode` (i suppose it's a private branch and nobody bases ones work on it)

```
--o--p--q--r--s   <-QA
   \/
   /\
--A--B--C--D--E   <-MyCode-backup
   \
    \b'-c'-d'-e'  <-MyCode
```

graph link `o-B` will be lost, but not the content of chain `B-E`.

```
git checkout MyCode
git branch MyCodeBackup  #this branch will keep original B-E reachable
gir rebase --no-ff A  #b'-e' recreation
git diff MyCode MyCodeBackup #for test - should give nothing - content equal
git diff QA...MyCode #supposedly of sane size
```

You can always `git reset --hard MyCodeBackup` to return to original state.

Comment: Running "git diff --name-only QA...MyCode" still returns a large number of files, 312 of them.

Comment: What you can try to do is - find _best common ancestor_ `git merge-base --all QA MyCode`. Supposedly it should be `41e68bb`. Then check, how branches diverged from common ancestor: `git diff --shortstat ancestor..QA` and `git diff --shortstat ancestor..MyCode`. Maybe it will clear the situation out

Comment: There are two bases (neither in my list of commits shown), I imagine there was a crisscross merge spanning over lots of commits.  Is this what's causing the number of files to be mis-reported?

Comment: I just tried the different diff-algorithm parameters on the diff, didn't seem to change anything.